# Why isn't this simple jQuery .append() working?

Tags: jquery, append

I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$( "#rev_slider_1_1_wrapper" ).append( "<p>Bacon</p>" )

});
```

However it is not appending: http://societyforlongbeachmusic.org/

Comment: at least check the errors thrown on your page before asking here. Will see that `$ is not defined`. Google search that error will find lots of posts about it

Comment: Next time you might want to create a fiddle instead of linking your page. It's not a place for advertisement.

Comment: jQuery is defined and $ is not. Is something using noConflict mode?

Answer (score 0):

```
var tpj=jQuery;
tpj.noConflict();  <--- no conflict mode
var revapi1;
```

Means $ is not defined, hence your error.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

Comment: Thank you. I changed it to `jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  $( "#rev_slider_1_1_wrapper" ).append( "<p>Bacon</p>" );
});`

Answer (score 0):

use $("#"+'<%=id.ClientID%>') it will work.Sometimes browser changes the id of the element based on the parent of the element mainly in contentPages